# Socialengine default layout change has no effect

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

I am using socialengine 4.2.I added some markup in Core\layouts\scripts default-simple.tpl and default.tpl but nothing seems to have an effect on front-end,even after flushing.I want to put a banner slider,for which I dont want to make a widget and put it on global header.I need to add some esternal scripts and css in the default layout,I guess, and then some markup in body.

1.I want to know,if need be, how to edit default layout.
2.Whats the difference between default-simple.tpl and default.tpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, you can edit layouts directly, and it works. Need more details how you tried it. And you can look into SE4 hooks (yes, more flexible and more complex way).

default.tpl:

```
echo $this->hooks('onRenderLayoutDefault', $this);
```

2) default-simple.tpl is auxiliary layout, it used for post-action messaging mostly, see Forum_TopicController::deleteAction() for example:

```
 return $this->_forward('success', 'utility', 'core', array(
'messages' => array(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->_('Topic deleted.')),
'layout' => 'default-simple',
'parentRedirect' => $forum->getHref(),
));
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to use Jquery. So,I added jquery and then tried to use "var $j = $.noConflict()" all in default.tpl inside script tag,so that its available everywhere.If I use it in each of my view,admin panel doesnt work well but jquery works  in view.How can I make it available everywhere.

Comment: I followed this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931344/how-to-use-jquery-hovercard-in-socialengine-4-framwork/12726490#12726490 but had problem as said above, with admin panel